# Hide tickmarks from yaxis in line chart of jqplot

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I want to remove tickmarks from y axis in line chart of jqplot. I have created multiple y axis line chart in jqplot, its work fine but I want to hide line of y2axis etc. I have write code for that but its hide only line display tickmarks. I want to hide both. See in below image.

[image]

I have write below code for hide yaxis line and tickmarks.

```
grid: {
    drawBorder: false,
    borderWidth:0, 
    shadow:false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show/hide the gridlines separately inside the axes options area:

```
axes: {
    xaxis: {
       tickOptions: {
          showGridline: true,
          showMark: true
       }
    },
    yaxis: {
       tickOptions: {
          showGridline: false,
          showMark: false
       }
    }
}
```

See [this section](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-axisTickRenderer-js.html#%24.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer.Properties) of the documentation for full details.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the showMark option? This is what I used to hide the ticks before... http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-axisTickRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer.showMark

Comment: @Askanison4 you might be right -- updated answer to have both. The question was somewhat unclear about the desired outcome